# Apache documentroot other local server

Tags: apache, virtualhost

I have a particular subdomain in my apache2 virtualhost 'httpd.conf' file that i would like to redirect to another local apache server. I have a router that redirects all requests on port 80 to the original server.

The second server is NOT on a different global IP address, but on a different local IP address.

Is there any way i can do this,

thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using Apache's proxy functionality.  For example:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
  ServerName myhostname

  <Location />
    ProxyPass http://address-of-local-server/
    ProxyPassReverse http://address-of-local-server/
  </Location>
</VirtualHost>
```

This will cause Apache to proxy requests that match this VirtualHost definition to another server and return the results to the client.

This presumes that you have `mod_proxy` enabled.

Answer (score 0):

You can mod proxy to any resource identified by it's IP address e.g

```
<VirtualHost *:80>

ServerName subdomain.domain.com
DocumentRoot /whatever
ProxyRequests Off

    <Proxy *>
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    </Proxy>

    <Location / >
    ProxyPass http://192.168.0.x
    ProxyPassReverse http://192.168.0.x
    </Location>

#...

</VirtualHost>
```